# AngularFire 7+ & Firebase 9+ errors with firebase package

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I get weird errors when running ' ionic serve --port 4200 --host 0.0.0.0 --configuration production_test --disable-host-check'. They started happening after upgrading to Angular 14, AngularFire 7 and Firebase 9.

Errors:

> [ng]
> ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-90ebcfae.js:600:29-40
>
> - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SD K_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default,
>   firebase) [ng] [ng]
>   ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-90ebcfae.js:787:19-31
> - Error: export '*getProvider' (imported as '* getProvider') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default,
>   firebase) [ng] [ng]
>   ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-90ebcfae.js:3043:6-17
> - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SD K_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default,
>   firebase) [ng] [ng]
>   ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-90ebcfae.js:12242:7-18
> - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'S DK_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default,
>   firebase) [ng] [ng]
>   ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-90ebcfae.js:12466:7-18
> - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'S DK_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default,
>   firebase) [ng] [ng]
>   ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-90ebcfae.js:12921:2-20
> - Error: export '_registerComponent' (importe d as '_registerComponent') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible
>   exports: __esModule, default, firebase) [ng] [ng]
>   ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-90ebcfae.js:12988:2-20
> - Error: export '_registerComponent' (importe d as '_registerComponent') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible
>   exports: __esModule, default, firebase) [ng] [ng]
>   ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-90ebcfae.js:13002:2-17
> - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported a s 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default,
>   firebase)

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sendnow",
  "version": "5.50.0",
  "available_languages": [
    {
      "name": "English",
      "code": "en"
    },
    {
      "name": "Dutch",
      "code": "nl"
    }
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "ecosystem:cordova"
  ],
  "license": "https://themeforest.net/licenses/terms/regular",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "serveProd": "ng serve --environment=prod",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "backupDBDEV": "firestore-backup-restore --accountCredentials sendnow-fdb.json --backupPath database-DEV.json",
    "restoreDBDEV": "firestore-backup-restore --restoreAccountCredentials sendnow-fdb.json --backupPath database-DEV.json",
    "backupDBSTAGING": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 --optimize_for_size --stack_size=6144 --trace-warnings && npm run bdbstaging",
    "bdbstaging": "firestore-export --accountCredentials sendnow-fdb.json --backupFile D:\\IdeaProjects\\SendNow-real-angularapp\\backups\\STAGING.json --nodePath environment/STAGING --prettyPrint",
    "post-build": "node ./build/post-build.js",
    "postinstall": "jetifier -r",
    "resources": "capacitor-resources -p android -i ./src/assets/images/logo-sendnow-white-bg-1024.png -s ./src/assets/images/splash.png"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "14.1.1",
    "@boring.devs/ngx-datatable": "^20.0.0",
    "@calvinnl/sendnow-ts-shared-components": "^1.115.5",
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.0.1",
    "@capacitor/app": "^1.0.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.0.1",
    "@capacitor/storage": "^1.2.3",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.33.1",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/battery-status": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.33.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.33.1",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.33.1",
    "@ionic-native/dialogs": "5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-analytics": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-messaging": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/foreground-service": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^5.33.1",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/power-management": "^5.33.1",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^5.33.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/web-intent": "^5.33.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.2.1",
    "@mdi/angular-material": "^6.4.95",
    "@ng-maps/core": "^3.0.0",
    "@ng-maps/google": "^3.0.0",
    "@ng-maps/marker-clusterer": "^3.0.0",
    "@ngu/carousel": "2.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "10.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "3.0.1",
    "@oasisdigital/angular-material-search-select": "1.1.1",
    "@sentry/angular": "^7.9.0",
    "@sentry/browser": "^7.9.0",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7.9.0",
    "@types/dragula": "3.7.0",
    "across-tabs": "1.3.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.8.0",
    "angular-star-rating": "^6.0.0",
    "angular2-hotkeys": "^13.1.0",
    "chart.js": "2.5.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "com-darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.12",
    "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "git+https://calvinturbo@bitbucket.org/TheBosZ/cordova-plugin-run-in-background.git",
    "cordova-plugin-battery-status": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-bgs-core": "^1.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-foreground-service": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-powermanagement-orig": "^1.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "core-js": "^3.12.1",
    "css-star-rating": "1.2.4",
    "date-fns": "1.28.5",
    "echarts": "4.9.0",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^9.9.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^11.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "hopscotch": "0.3.1",
    "i18n-iso-countries": "4.3.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "js-marker-clusterer": "1.0.0",
    "localforage": "1.9.0",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "ng-connection-service": "1.0.4",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ng2-dragula": "2.1.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.4.0",
    "ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
    "ngforage": "6.0.0",
    "ngx-avatars": "^1.4.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "5.3.8",
    "ngx-echarts": "4.2.2",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^4.2.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.2",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "4.8.0",
    "ngx-scrollbar": "^10.0.1",
    "npm": "^8.1.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.3.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "8.1.0",
    "postcss-scss": "^3.0.5",
    "quill": "1.3.7",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.6",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-pausable": "^1.0.0",
    "safe-json-stringify": "^1.2.0",
    "signature_pad": "^3.0.0-beta.4",
    "socket.io-client": "2.3.1",
    "thenby": "1.3.4",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "tslint-to-eslint-config": "1.5.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "5.0.5",
    "uuid": "3.4.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.1401.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "14.1.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^3.0.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/echarts": "^4.9.7",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/hopscotch": "0.2.28",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/mousetrap": "^1.6.8",
    "@types/node": "^6.14.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^3.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.4.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.3.0",
    "cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "first-input-delay": "^0.1.3",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.5.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.8",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.6.4",
    "typescript-eslint": "0.0.1-alpha.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/mousetrap": "1.6.8",
    "webpack": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "bit": {
    "env": {
      "compiler": "bit.envs/compilers/typescript@3.1.46"
    },
    "componentsDefaultDirectory": "components/{name}",
    "packageManager": "npm"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "electron"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "ionic_generate_source_map": "true"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1754#issuecomment-491566739

Answer (score 0):

Not the greatest solution, but I downgraded AngularFire & Firebase to the last major version. It seems to work with Angular 14 although not officially supported.

Comment: What versions did you end up using. I have the same issue.